# How to produce bundles including all node modules from vue app?

Tags: vue.js, npm

Using the usual `vue-cli-service build` only includes dependencies actually used by the app.

Comment: Why do you want to achieve it?

Comment: @imcvampire to include in hugo (for example). Basically I am viewing npm install like an environment setup for hugo posts. Want a semi global scope of bunded js libs available. It is probably taking me into this weird direction. I don't actually care that they are bundled, just want to use npm to handle the installs, includes etc. no manual inclusions anywhere bc of deep dependency hierarchies. Open to any good way to do this really.

Comment: You might want to checkout [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) it allows you to include all files in a (posts) directory.